Finding the normal representation of extensive form game
Consider a game where player 1 must choose T or B, player 2 must choose L or R, and their
payoffs depend on their choices as follows.
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{P1} \backslash \text{P2} & L & R \\
\hline
\text{T} & (3,2) & (1,1) \\
\text{B} & (4,3) & (2,4) \\
\end{array}
$$
Suppose that player 1 moves first, and then player 2 makers her choice after observing 1's move.
But also suppose that, whatever 1 chooses, the probability that player 2 will correctly observe 1's action is 0.9, and there is probability 0.1 that player 2 will mistakenly observe the other action (which 1 did not choose).
The payoffs depend on the players' actual choices according to the previous table (so, for example, if 1 chose T but 2 mistakenly observed B and chose R then 2's payoff would be 1).
Show : The normal representation in strategic form for the extensive-form game.

Note: This question is a variation of a previous version of a problem, which does not involve player 2 mistakenly observing player 1's move. In this case, the normal representation in strategic form for the extensive-form game is as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
1 \ / (2.\text{T}/2.\text{B}) & \text{Ll} & \text{Lr} & \text{Rl} & \text{Rr} \\
\hline
\text{T} & (3,2) & (3,2) & (1,1) & (1,1) \\
\text{B} & (4,3) & (2,4) & (4,3) & (2,4) \\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\text{P1} \backslash \text{P2} & \text{Ll} & \text{Lr} & \text{Rl} & \text{Rr} \\
\hline
\text{T} & (3,2) & 0.9\cdot(3,2) + 0.1\cdot(1,1)  & 0.9\cdot(1,1) + 0.1\cdot(3,2) & (1,1) \\
\text{B} & (4,3) & 0.1\cdot(4,3) + 0.9\cdot(2,4) & 0.1\cdot(2,4) + 0.9\cdot(4,3) & (2,4) \\
\end{array}
$$
where a strategy Xy of player 2 denotes that they will choose X if they observe T, and Y if they observe B.
Note the coincidence with previous exercise's payoff matrix if we change probability of successful observation from 0.9 to 1.
